# Capture keydown event in userscript and hide it from the website

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, keyboard-events, userscripts

I need to capture a keydown event in a userscript, and hide the event from the website itself. I.e. the website should not be able to detect the keypress.

I tried the following code in a Greasemonkey userscript:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        test
// @namespace   www.robertnitsch.de
// @description test
// @include     https://www.robertnitsch.de/test/
// @version     1
// @grant       none
// ==/UserScript==

document.addEventListener("keydown", function(evt) {
    console.log("userscript", evt);
    evt.stopPropagation();
    return false;
}, true);
```

However, the page can still detect the keydown event, as can be verified on my test website: https://www.robertnitsch.de/test/

I am testing with simple keys like a, s, d, etc.

Comment: Yes, jQuery can be used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         test
// @namespace    http://stackoverflow.com
// @version      1.0
// @description  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25631170/capture-keydown-event-in-userscript-and-hide-it-from-the-website
// @include      https://www.robertnitsch.de/test/
// @author       zanetu
// @grant        none
// @run-at       document-start
// ==/UserScript==

document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
}, true);
```

Comment: Awesome, it works! I didn't know about `@run-at` and `stopImmediatePropagation()`. :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
$('*').off('keyup keydown keypress');
});
    </script>
</head>

<body>
test
</body>
</html>
```

Above code works!!

Check and confirm!!

Comment: Sorry, but this is not what I'm after. I cannot change the source code of the actual website.